# Undefined reference error but symbol existing in the library

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I get an `undefined reference` error for the example below. I have seen lots of questions that relate to this issue but believe I gave a stripped, reproducible, conceptual example as opposed specific issues in other questions,

dynlib.h:

```
void printMe_dyn();
```

dynlib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dynlib.h"

void printMe_dyn() {
  printf("I am execuded from a dynamic lib");
}
```

myapp.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dynlib.h"

int main() 
{
    printMe_dyn();
    return 0;
}
```

Build steps:

```
gcc -Wall -fpic -c dynlib.c
gcc -shared -o libdynlib.so dynlib.o
gcc -Wall -L. -ldynlib myapp.c -o myapp
```

Error:

```
/tmp/ccwb6Fnv.o: In function `main':
myapp.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `printMe_dyn'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Proof that the symbol is in the library:

```
nm libdynlib.so | grep printMe_dyn
00000000000006e0 T printMe_dyn
```

1. *Am I using the correct compiler flags for building the dynamic
   library?*
2. *Is the proof I've presented really an unambiguous proof?*
3. *What other approach could be taken to diagnose the issue?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of appearance of libraries *matter*.

To quote the [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z` after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `z`, those functions may not be loaded.

You should be changing your compilation statement to

```
gcc -o myapp -Wall -L. myapp.c -ldynlib
```

to tell `gcc` to search for the *symbols* used in (compiled) `myapp.c` to be present in `dynlib`.

Answer (score 5):

Just as additional notice. The same behavior one may obtain when the library has been built by gcc and linked to the c++ project. Like follows:

```
gcc -Wall -fpic -c dynlib.c
gcc -shared -o libdynlib.so dynlib.o
g++ -o myapp -Wall -L. myapp.cpp -ldynlib
```

In such case the reason is name-mangling used by g++. To have it turned off one must wrap C-function prototypes by `extern "C"` within C-library. For example like follows:

dynlib.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
void printMe_dyn();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of libraries in linker command line matters. Fix:

```
gcc -o myapp -Wall -L. myapp.c -ldynlib
```